# root: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by root)

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, root, glibc, ubuntu-20.04

I am very new to this so please be patient with me, my apologies.

I am trying to open CERN ROOT using WSL 1 on Window 10 with ubuntu version 20.04. I have installed all the dependencies as directed by the CERN website, yet when I type root into my terminal I am faced with the error `root: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.34 not found (required by root)`

I have tried

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libc6
```

Yet it gives me this message

```
libc6 is already the newest version (2.31-0ubuntu9.14).
```

I am unsure how to get about fixing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The dependencies I installed I will leave in the following lines

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev cmake g++ gcc binutils libx11-dev libxpm-dev \
libxft-dev libxext-dev python3 libssl-dev libafterimage0

sudo apt-get install gfortran libpcre3-dev \
xlibmesa-glu-dev libglew-dev libftgl-dev \
libmysqlclient-dev libfftw3-dev libcfitsio-dev \
graphviz-dev libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev \
libldap2-dev python3-dev python3-numpy libxml2-dev libkrb5-dev \
libgsl0-dev qtwebengine5-dev nlohmann-json3-dev
```

Comment: Whatever you're starting requires glibc 2.34 and you have 2.31. The glibc vesion is pretty much fixed by the Distribution/Version you have, so you'll have to pick a newer Ubuntu version that has the required glibc (22.04 would be a LTS candidate). Did you check the requirement for the software you're installing?

Comment: I hadn't checked it as I had previously installed this on my laptop and ran into no problems, which was naïve of me to assume it would work the same. I was instructed via my supervisor that using Ubuntu 20.04 was the best thing I could use as it was compatible with ROOT.

Comment: It works for me. I just tried the one under Ubuntu 20.04 here: https://root.cern/releases/release-63002/

Comment: I managed to follow this however ran into this error message when trying to run root
/home/jw3153/root/bin/root.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libxxhash.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory